# Height one prime ideal of arithmetical rank greater than 1

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local domain which is not a UFD and let $P$ be a height one prime ideal of $R.$ Can we find an element $x\in P$ such that $P$ is the only minimal prime ideal containing $x$?

Comment: If we use Krull's height Theorem, then we can say that $P$ is minimal over an element $y\in R$. Since $R$ is Noetherian, we know that there are only finitely many minimal primes $P_i$ over (y). We may find a new element $x$ that avoids all these $P_i$, but there might be other primes that might be minimal over this new element $x$. So now i feel that the above statement might be false, but i have no counterexample.

Comment: Related to [Regular local ring and a prime ideal generated by a regular sequence up to radical](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163700/regular-local-ring-and-a-prime-ideal-generated-by-a-regular-sequence-up-to-radic).

Answer (score 4):

I'll prove @messi's assertion that $R_\mathfrak{m}$, where $R=k[X,Y,U,V]/(XV-YU)$ and $\mathfrak{m}=(X,Y,U,V)/(XV-YU)$, is a counterexample to the question, that is, there exists $P$ a height one prime ideal of $R_\mathfrak{m}$ which is not generated up to radical by a single element. In other words, the arithmetical rank of $P$ is greater than $1$.

Let's write $R=k[x,y,u,v]$ with $xv=yu$. Then $R$ is a noetherian graded $k$-algebra with $\dim R=3$. Moreover, Proposition 14.5 from R. Fossum, *The Divisor Class Group of a Krull Domain*, tells us that $R$ is a Krull domain and its divisor class group $\operatorname{Cl}(R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}.$ Take $\mathfrak{p}=(x,y)$. It's easy to check that $\mathfrak{p}$ is a height one prime ideal of $R$ and from Fossum we also know that $[\mathfrak{p}]$, the class of $\mathfrak{p}$, generates $\operatorname{Cl}(R)$. Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}=\sqrt{aR}$. Since $aR$ is a divisorial ideal it follows that $aR=\mathfrak{p}^{(t)}$, $t\ge 1$. This implies that $[\mathfrak{p}]$ is a torsion element of $\operatorname{Cl}(R)$, a contradiction. Now we can pass from $R$ to $R_\mathfrak{m}$ by using Corollary 10.3 from the same book.

**Remark.** In the view of curious' answer form this related [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163700/regular-local-ring/177684#177684), another way to solve this problem is to show that the local cohomology module $H_\mathfrak{p}^2(R)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $R$ is a Dedekind domain.  Then height one prime ideals are the same as non-zero prime ideals, and are also the same as maximal ideals.  If $x \in R$ is such that $P$ (some given non-zero prime ideal) is the only prime ideal containing $x$, then the factorization of $(x)$ into non-zero prime ideals contains just copies of $P$, and so $(x) = P^n$ for some $n$.  Thus another way to phrase your question in this case is to ask whether or not $P$ is of finite order in the class group of $R$.

This is not true in general, because the class group of a Dedekind domain need not be finite in general.  E.g. $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 + x)$  has infinite class group.

Added: I overlooked the fact that the OP asked for a local ring.  I hope to add a counterexample satisfying this condition.

Comment: I asked the question with the hypothesis being local Noetherian domain which is not a UFD.

Comment: @messi: Dear messi, Ah, I didn't notice that you wanted a local example.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

@Matt E A counterexample should be $S=R_m$, where $R=k[x,y,u,v]/(xv-yu)$ and $m=(x,y,u,v)/(xv-yu)$. But i cant check(or prove) in an elementary way that for every $b\in (x,y)$(which is a height 1 minimal prime), there is another minimal prime $P$ containing $b$.